# Disabling triggers in Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm running a migration script on my local machine and have some statements similar to this.

```
ALTER TABLE "TableName" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

The migration runs successfully on my local machine but I'm having problems getting the script to work on the Postgres database on Heroku. I've also tried the following statement.

```
ALTER TABLE "TableName" DISABLE TRIGGER USER;
```

This doesn't work either. And here is the following error message I receive.

```
ERROR:  23503: insert or update on table "Test" violates foreign key constraint "Test_pageID_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (pageID)=(152) is not present in table "Page".
SCHEMA NAME:  public
TABLE NAME:  Test
CONSTRAINT NAME:  Test_pageID_fkey
LOCATION:  ri_ReportViolation, ri_triggers.c:3271
Time: 80.460 ms
```

I believe the issue here is that I'm not a superuser and cannot disable all triggers for the database. The triggers are disabled locally but not disabled on Heroku despite the above statements being invoked. Any ideas on how to disable triggers in Heroku?

Comment: happened to mo too... were you able to solve it?

Comment: have you tried disabling them table by table? 

(in general it's a risky thing regarding data integrity to disable triggers, but fine if you know exactly what you are doing and take care of referential integrity yourself)